# SQL multiple columns WHERE condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | d |
| 2 | b | e |
| 3 | c | f |

and very large .csv file (about 1M rows). It contains Columns A, B and C.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | a | d |
| 5 | b | w |
| 6 | c | f |

I need to extract rows from table where (B = 'a' and C = 'd') or (B = 'b' and C = 'w') or (B = 'c' and C = 'f')

Result will be:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | d |
| 3 | c | f |

I've tried query like in description, but it's too large for request (1M rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically trying to join on the columns `(b, c)` manually. However, SQL knows how to do a join more efficiently.

Import the CSV file as a temporary table, analyze it, create a multi-column index on its `(b, c)`, then do a join like this:

```
SELECT R.*
FROM realTable R
JOIN csvTable C
  ON R.b = C.b AND R.c = C.c;
```